# Hibernate Criteria with self join

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Have been learning Hibernate, Spring and JPA the last week and got stuck on trying to create a Criteria for the following scenario:

Let's say I have 2 tables:

**Game**

- id

**PlayedGame**

- id
- account_ref -> reference to some account table
- game_id -> reference to the game

Entity mapping:

```
Game {

 @id
 Long id;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "game")
 Set<Player> players;

}

PlayedGame {

 @id
 Long id;

 Long account_ref;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "game_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 Game game;
}
```

Now I want to query for the following scenario:
 - I want to find all games a specific player (P) has played where player (A) was a part of it. More specifically that two people belonging to the same game

In SQL this could be done with something like (which the query should be):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.* FROM Player as p1 
INNER JOIN Player as p2 ON p1.game_id=p2.game_id 
WHERE p1.account_ref=P AND p2.account_ref=A
```

Can this be done neatly with Criteria in Hibernate?

Comment: Depends on your Entity mappings and as you haven't posted them.....

Comment: Created an entity mapping now

Comment: The friend part is very ambiguous, are you saying that two people belonging to the same game?

Comment: Yes, two people(player) can belong to the same game. And the question it what games did they share together. Changed the description a little bit

Comment: Isn't  the relationship between Player <> Game many-to-many then?

Comment: One game can have many players, one player has one game - don't see the many to many relation. I just wrote down a simplified syntax from http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html

Comment: "*I want to find **all games** a specific player (P) has played*"

Comment: PlayedGame.account_ref does not reference to Game. Account_ref is a foreign_key to a different table pretty much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe possible with Hibernate's Criteria API, but not straight forward.

A simple case would require the same association path to be join twice (one for *A* and one for *P*):

```
Criteria gameCriteria = ((HibernateEntityManager) em).getSession().createCriteria(Game.class);

Criteria playedGamesOfACriteria = gameCriteria.createCriteria("playedGames", "pga");
Criteria accountOfACriteria = playedGamesOfACriteria.createCriteria("account", "a");
accountOfACriteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(a.id));

Criteria playedGamesOfPCriteria = gameCriteria.createCriteria("playedGames", "pgp");
Criteria accountOfPCriteria = playedGamesOfPCriteria.createCriteria("account", "p");
accountOfPCriteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(p.id));

return gameCriteria.list();
```

This won't work due to [HHH-879](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879).

But you can use a JPA query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
        "select g "
        + "from Game g "
        + "join g.playedGames pga "
        + "join pga.account a "
        + "join g.playedGames pgp "
        + "join pgp.account p "
        + "where a = ?1 and p = ?2"
);
q.setParameter(1, a);
q.setParameter(2, p);
return q.getResultList();
```

This is even less code.

Also: Some consider the Criteria API to be [deprecated](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7882?focusedCommentId=55941&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-55941).