# JPA Criteria API and two joins on the same path expression

Tags: java, jpa, self-join

My problem is very similar to this old question: [Hibernate Criteria with self join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029593/hibernate-criteria-with-self-join) but I'd need a non-Hibernate specific, clean JPA solution for identical problem. I use Hibernate 4.3 at the moment as a JPA provider, but I can update it if necessary. I have following entities:

- **Game**, which can have many *Result* entries, one per each player that played it
- **GameResult** owned by a **Game** and referencing a player who took a part. It has no back reference to the owning *Game*
- **Player** who played a game.

Now I want to create a query that finds all games that I played against a particular opponent and retrieve our scores. I got following JPA query:

```
String strQuery = "SELECT g, my_result, their_result FROM Game g JOIN g.results my_result JOIN  g.results their_result WHERE my_result.player=:p1 AND their_result.player=:p2";
```

It seems to work, but I'd like to transform it to Criteria API, and I am a complete noob when it comes to Criteria API. I got following for a start:

```
Root<Game> game = query.from(Game.class);
Join<Game, GameResult> result_mine = game.join("results");
```

So far, so easy. But now I have no idea how to get `result_theirs` joined with this part. I tried following:

```
Join<Game, GameResult> result_theirs = game.join("results");
result_mine.join( *what should I put here* , result_theirs);

//or:
Selection<Game> alias_game = game.alias("g");
Join result_theirs = result_mine.join(alias_game, "results"); //does not compile

//or:
Join result_theirs = result_mine.join(game.get("results")); //does not compile


//or:
Join<Game, GameResult> result_theirs = game.join("results");
result_mine.join(result_theirs); //does not compile
```

I am missing something, but I have no idea what, or maybe I am going in a wrong direction.

So, what am I doing wrong and how can I translate above JPA query into Criteria API code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 3rd or is correct except you are joining it twice

Your line `result_mine.join(result_theirs);` tries to join the `GameResult` to `GameResult` which cannot be done as your Entity mapping only specified how to join `Game` to `GameResult`(but not GameResult to GameResult) the former is already done by `Join<Game, GameResult> result_theirs = game.join("results");`

So do Something like below

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Game> game = query.from(Game.class);
Join<Game, GameResult> result_mine = game.join("results");
Join<Game, GameResult> result_theirs = game.join("results");
query
        .multiselect(game, result_mine, result_theirs)
        .where(
                cb.equal(result_mine.get("player"),p1),
                cb.equal(result_theirs.get("player"),p2)
        );
List<Tuple> results = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that what I was missing is the fact, that calling `game.join("results")` not only returns join object, but also mutates `game` root itself, and all sequentially performed joins modify it (what is sensible, I just somehow did not grasp it). Now I got it (hopefully). Now things work as they should.